# How to include a spring-boot-maven-plugin generated jar to a third application

Tags: spring-boot, classloader, noclassdeffounderror, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I create an application that depends on `a.jar`, which was generated by the spring-boot-maven-plugin. `a.jar` depends itself on another `b.jar`, which is located it its `lib\` folder. When I start my application, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: some_class_located_in_b.jar
```

It is possible to add a spring-boot-maven-plugin generated jar to the classpath of a third application? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

The repackaged jar is a "final" artifact and represents your application: you shouldn't have a module dependency on it. The default behaviour of `repackage` is to *replace* your regular jar with the one that holds the application.

If the code of project `a` is meant to be shared as a module, please make sure to specify a `classifier` for the repackaged jar. That way you can use the regular jar file as a *module* dependency

There is [an example in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html)